# Resolve function resolving wrong view_name in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

- **Django 4.0**
- **Python 3.9**

I recently upgraded my django project from 3.14 to 4.0 and django.urls.resolve function seems broken. Resolve is always returning app_name.views.view instead of app_name.views.actual_function_name.

Here is my code -

```
path = request.path
match = resolve(path)
view_name = match.view_name
```

after the above code "view_name" variable is always "view" irrespective of the url. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

P.S. if there is any other way, I can find out the function from a url without using resolve, please let me know that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue and it's in the way we define our urls.

I had defined my urls like this before

```
path('some-path/', views.view_name)
```

for this url in Django 3.1.4, the resolve function was working properly. But with the update to Django 4.0, the default view_name is view. That's why the resolve function is returning view_name as "view" every time irrespective of url.

For resolve function to work properly, I had to update my urls with the additional name parameter like below -

```
path('some-path/', views.view_name, name='path-name')
```

After changing the urls like this, now the resolve with return 'path-name' when passed with url.

Answer (score 0):

Try call [func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.func) from your `resolve(path)`

```py
from django.urls import resolve

path = request.path
match = resolve(path)
view_function = match.func
```

for class-based views `view_function = match.func.view_class`

Comment: match.func provides me this value - <function View.as_view.<locals>.view , every time irrespective of the url called. That's the issue. @weAreStarsDust

Comment: If you are using class-based views, try `match.func.view_class`

Comment: No, we are using function based views only. If you want to me post additional code, Please let me know. The code was working perfectly before I upgraded the project from 3.1.4 to 4.0 (django) and 3.11.0 to 3.14.0 (DRF). Now, after upgrading, the resolve function is returning "view" as the function name every time, irrespective of the url. I tried debugging the Django code, but could not pinpoint where django is picking the view.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info or code

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any change for the mentioned part of the library from 3.14 to 4.0.
According to the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) you can get view, url_name and view_name from resolve like this:

```
# Resolve a URL
match = resolve('/some/path/')

# The name of the URL pattern that matches the URL.
print(match.url_name)  

# The view function that would be used to serve the URL.
print(match.func)

# The name of the view that matches the URL, including the namespace if there is one.
print(match.view_name)
```

If this is not working for you then maybe problem is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4.0, the `django.urls.resolve()` function has been deprecated and replaced with `django.urls.resolve_match()` which returns a `ResolverMatch` object. This object contains additional information about the resolved view function.

```
from django.urls import resolve_match

path = request.path
match = resolve_match(path)
view_function = match.func
actual_function_name = view_function.__name__
```